# What is the correct understanding about ScrollBar syntax in QtQuick/QML?

Tags: qt, syntax, qml, scrollbar

Recently, I used a `Scrollbar` with a `TableView`. I referred to 
[QML documentation for ScrollBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollbar.html) and I can see an example:

```
Flickable {
    focus: true

    Keys.onUpPressed: scrollBar.decrease()
    Keys.onDownPressed: scrollBar.increase()

    ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar { id: scrollBar }
}
```

I thought that `ScrollBar.vertical` is a bool variant, but why there is an object `ScrollBar { id: scrollBar }` after colon?

Is there any documentation about this syntax?

What is the difference between using

1. ```
   ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar { id: scrollBar }
   ```

   and
2. ```
   ScrollBar { id: scrollBar; orientation: Qt.Vertical }
   ```

The same confusion came to me with the code below:

```
Flickable {
    anchors.fill: parent

    contentWidth: parent.width * 2
    contentHeight: parent.height * 2

    ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar { id: hbar; active: vbar.active }
    ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar { id: vbar; active: hbar.active }
}
```

On the line `anchors.fill: parent`, `anchors` is lower-case.

Answer (score 2):

> *I thought that `ScrollBar.vertical` is a bool variant, but why there is an object `ScrollBar { id: scrollBar }` after the colon?*

The answer is simply because `ScrollBar.vertical` is neither a bool nor a variant but has a type of `ScrollBar`. This is stated in the documentation.

> ### `ScrollBar.vertical : ScrollBar`
>
> This property attaches a vertical scroll bar to a Flickable.
>
> ```
> Flickable {
>     contentHeight: 2000
>     ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar { }
> }
> ```

Note the subheader tells us the type after the colon: `ScrollBar`.

### Is there any documentation about this syntax?

Yes there is. I copied the above from [*this page*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollbar.html#vertical-attached-prop).

### What is the difference between using [...]

I'll walk through each confusing line of code and label each one with its name.

```
//  Attached Property
ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar { id: scrollBar }

//  Child Object
ScrollBar { id: scrollBar; orientation: Qt.Vertical }

//  Grouped Property
anchors.fill: parent
```

Let's go through these one-by-one.

### Attached Properties

> *Attached properties* [...] are mechanisms that enable objects to be annotated with extra properties or signal handlers that are otherwise unavailable to the object. In particular, they allow objects to access properties or signals that are specifically relevant to the individual object.
>
> References to attached properties [...] take the following syntax form:
>
> ```
> <AttachingType>.<propertyName>
> ```
>
> For example, the `ListView` type has an attached property `ListView.isCurrentItem` that is available to each delegate object in a `ListView`. This can be used by each individual delegate object to determine whether it is the currently selected item in the view:
>
> ```
> import QtQuick 2.0
>    
> ListView {
>     width: 240; height: 320
>     model: 3
>     delegate: Rectangle {
>         width: 100; height: 30
>         color: ListView.isCurrentItem ? "red" : "yellow"
>     }
> }
> ```

> In this case, the name of the attaching type is `ListView` and the property in question is `isCurrentItem`, hence the attached property is referred to as `ListView.isCurrentItem`.

<sup>*[(source)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#attached-properties-and-attached-signal-handlers)*</sup>

In our particular case, `ScrollBar` is the *attaching type* and `vertical` is the *property*.

Keep in mind that there are several differences between `ListView.isCurrentItem` and `ScrollBar.vertical`. The former is of type `bool` while the latter is of type `ScrollBar`. Additionally, the former is a `read-only` property, meaning that we can't assign or change it. On the other hand, you can assign to `ScrollBar.vertical`.

If `ListView.isCurrentItem` *wasn't* read-only, we could've assigned it like we did with `ScrollBar.vertical`.

```
delegate: Rectangle {
    ListView.isCurrentItem: true
}
```

But since it is read-only, this raises an error.

### Child Objects

This is QML basics right here. Here's an example:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 800; height: 600
    
    //  child object of ApplicationWindow
    Rectangle { 
        width: 200; height: 200
        color: "red"

        //  child object of Rectangle
        Text { text: "Hello World" }
    }
    
    //  child object of ApplicationWindow
    Rectangle {
        x: 400
        width: 200; height: 200
        color: "blue"
    }
}
```

Looking back at `ScrollBar`:

```
Flickable {
    ScrollBar { id: scrollBar; orientation: Qt.Vertical }
}
```

This will instantiate a child object `ScrollBar` but that's it. No added functionality.

### Grouped Properties

> In some cases properties contain a logical group of sub-property attributes. These sub-property attributes can be assigned to using either the dot notation or group notation.
>
> For example, the `Text` type has a font group property. Below, the first `Text` object initializes its `font` values using dot notation, while the second uses group notation:
>
> ```
> Text {
>     // dot notation
>     font.pixelSize: 12
>     font.b: true
> }
> ```
>
> ```
> Text {
>     // group notation
>     font { pixelSize: 12; b: true }
> }
> ```

<sup>[*(source)*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#grouped-properties)</sup>

Another common example of a grouped property is `anchors` (as you may have noted).

Don't let the dot notation confuse you. Try to spot a generic difference between the two properties below:

```
anchors.top
ScrollBar.vertical
```

The important distinction to make is that **properties must begin with a lower-case letter** whereas **QML types begin with an upper-case letter**. With this in mind, we can see that `anchors` is clearly a property while `ScrollBar` is a type.

---

With those out of the way, I think we can try to address one more issue.

## Why use attached properties instead of defining `ScrollBar` as a child object?

Because of better automation. From documentation:

> When `ScrollBar` is attached vertically or horizontally to a `Flickable`, its geometry and the following properties are automatically set and updated as appropriate:

> - orientation
> - position
> - size
> - active

> An attached `ScrollBar` re-parents itself to the target `Flickable`. A vertically attached `ScrollBar` resizes itself to the height of the `Flickable`, and positions itself to either side of it based on the layout direction. A horizontally attached `ScrollBar` resizes itself to the width of the `Flickable`, and positions itself to the bottom.

<sup>[*(source)*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollbar.html#attaching-scrollbar-to-a-flickable)</sup>

This allows you to focus on other things, instead of worrying about the position of the scrollbar.

But sure, instantiating `ScrollBar` as a child object (non-attached) also has it merits.

> It is possible to create an instance of `ScrollBar` without using the attached property API. This is useful when the behavior of the attached scroll bar is not sufficient or a `Flickable` is not in use. [...]
>
> When using a non-attached ScrollBar, the following must be done manually:
>
> - Layout the scroll bar (with the x and y or anchor properties, for example).
> - Set the size and position properties to determine the size and position of the scroll bar in relation to the scrolled item.
> - Set the active property to determine when the scroll bar will be visible.

<sup>[*(source)*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollbar.html#non-attached-scroll-bars)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your  detailed explanation.